# How to remove vertical lines left by tab spaces in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use tab space in VSCode it remains a vertical line for each tab as in picture below. How can I remove them?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Editor > Guides: Indentation` setting controls whether or not those lines are rendered. Just uncheck that box and you should stop seeing them.

[image: vscode settings screen]
*It's the bottom box in this image*

---

**Update based on comments:** I don't think the editor can selectively render some indent guides while hiding the rest, all 'TAB SPACES' before text count as indentation to it. If you're only doing this with comments for some visual reason, you can simply start the comment early and put the spaces later like so:

*Before*:
[image: before changes]

*After*:
[image: after changes]

Comment: These settings removes all guide lines. I ONLY want remove the vertical lines of TAB SPACES like the picture.

Comment: @BahadorKhajehmiri does the update help?

Comment: Good idea :)) Why didn't I think of that?!

Answer (score 3):

VS Code has options to hide/show indent guides. Steps to configure are as below.

1. Open VS Code Settings [ Cmd + Shift + P / Ctrl + Shift + P ]
2. Search for 'settings' and select **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings**
3. Now in settings, search for 'editor>guides'
4. Uncheck **Editor > Guides: Indentation** to remove guides.

[image: VS Code Settings screenshot1]

You can also choose to hide or show **Editor › Guides: Highlight Active Indentation**

Comment: Like previous answer your solution removes all guide lines. I ONLY want remove the vertical lines of TAB SPACES like the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, instead of trying to disable the lines, I decided to change the colors to transparent. Heres my settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  // BRACKET PAIR
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#ffffff22",
  "editorIndentGuide.background1": "#00000001",
  // LINE NUMBERS
  "editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#ffffff55",
  "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#ffffff11",
  // GIT LINES
  "editorGutter.addedBackground": "#00000000",
  "editorGutter.deletedBackground": "#00000000",
  "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#00000000"
},
```

[image]

I just play with the colors until I catch the one I like